# Nginx неправильный путь при открытии файлов

Tags: django, nginx

Я развернул nginx, gunicorn, supervisor и django на сервере. Но сайт не работает и я получаю 404 ошибку.
Однако, если я запускаю виртуальное окружение и manage.py runserver на моём ip адресе , то сайт работает и всё подтягивается корректно.

в файле **settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

файл **nginx**

```
upstream my_app_server {
  server unix:/webapps/my_project/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

    listen   80;
    server_name my_project_IP_address;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /webapps/my_project/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /webapps/my_project/logs/nginx-error.log;
 
    location /static/ {
        alias   /webapps/my_project/my_project/static/;
    }
    
    location /media/ {
        alias   /webapps/my_project/my_project/media/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://my_project_app_server;
            break;
        }
    }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
        location = /500.html {
            root /webapps/my_project/my_project/static/;
        }
    }
```

Но почему-то nginx при запросе клиента, что бы отобразить статик файлы, которые указаны в settings.py и по пути /webapps/my_project/my_project/static/ пытается вытянуть их из /usr/share/nginx/html/admin. Код ошибки ниже. Подскажите, в чём может быть ошибка ?

> 2021/04/06 09:56:51 [error] 55121#55121: *1 open()
> "/usr/share/nginx/html/admin" failed (2: No such file or directory),
> client: "my_IP_client", server: "my_IP_server",  request: "GET /admin
> HTTP/1.1", host: "my_IP_server"

Comment: `"GET /admin` — где тут слово static?

Comment: @AlexeyTen его тут нет. Но почему тогда он не запрашивает ?

Comment: Не запрашивает что? И, кстати, где proxy_pass? Хотя обычно у джанго же uwsgi?

Comment: Вы бы хоть разобрались по логам что у вас не работает. Вопрос об одном, ошибка про другое...

Comment: @AndreyMihalev спасибо за предельное объяснение. И в чём ошибка ?

Comment: В том, что вы не прописали proxy_pass

Comment: @andreymal спасибо указал, всё заработало.